# Is it possible to overwrite a variable in another file

Tags: php, wordpress

Forgive me if this is one of those dumb questions.

I'm writing a theme for wordpress and making use of PHP variables to communicate between files.

```
<?php
    $somevar = 'cat';
    $display = 10;
    include 'cat_display.php';
?>
```

It has suddenly ocured to me that while I am including my own files, Wordpress must be including my files. What if those variables that I think I have declared have already been declared up the chain and hold something important.

The last thing I want to do is open my .htaccess for abuse or have something unmeaningful added to the database.

```
$user_id = 10; // Oops just granted uberuser status to WillyWonka
```

Do I have anything to worry about?

Comment: I would put your variables in a unique array ie `$waldermots_vars`

Comment: @ChristopherMorrissey Thanks for the tip. It's a shame tutorials over simplify these things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it certainly is.

You could rename your variables `$yourinitials_somevar` to avoid the problem.

[edit]Or put them in an array, as Christopher says in the question comments.

Answer (score 0):

When [developing WordPress plugins](https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin) it's common to encapsulate variables by:

- Using a unique prefix: `$mywpp_var`
- Using an associative array: `$mywpp['var']`

Comment: I have read the link you provided before and it doesn't mention naming schemes.

Comment: It does not mention variables specifically. It mentioned prefixes for functions and using an array is common practice.